Why do I get a "Unable to find connector client." error when using restFunctionService
I try to build a restful service using matlab's restFunctionService api, but I get an error when I run it.
mySqrt.m：
function result = mySqrt(x)
    result = sqrt(x);
end


mySqrtService.m
serviceL = restFunctionService("EL",["mySqrt"],ClientAccessMode="remote");

matlab version is 2024a.
result image

Can someone tell me what is going on?
I tried reinstalling Matlab, but it didn't solve the problem.
